# read system call taking reading from STDIN

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, system

When does the Read System call terminates when taking input from STDIN ??

Comment: I am not a downvoter,but Its is supposed to be a good manner to ask question for a short answer...

Comment: ok I got you but it was my first post thats why it  happened.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few parts to this.

First, let's clarify the distinction between OS-level IO and stdio-level IO. `read(2)` and `write(2)` (POSIX IO) are specified by POSIX, and operate using file descriptors (numbers starting from 0); `fread(3)` and `fwrite(3)` (stdio IO) are specified by ISO C and operate on file handles, such as `STDIN`, which on POSIX systems encapsulate file descriptors and add some things (such as output buffering) on top of them.

So, `read(2)` and `write(2)` don't do any buffering on their own. The buffering you see on standard input (file descriptor `0`, **not** `STDIN`, which is one abstraction above that) is done by the terminal (or terminal emulation). Search for canonical mode to disable it.

At the stdio-level, `fwrite(3)` (and `printf(3)`, `fprintf(3)`, et al.) does output buffering depending on what the output is connected to.

See also:
[How to check if a key was pressed in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962263/checking-if-a-key-was-pressed)
[Single characters are not printed on the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559917/single-characters-are-not-printed-on-the-terminal)

[Does printing to the screen cause a switch to kernel mode and running OS code in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476438/does-printing-to-the-screen-cause-a-switch-to-kernel-mode-and-running-os-code-in)